# Why does GNU parallel become less and less effective?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu, tls1.2, gnu-parallel

I have a file containing 1 000 000 domain names and I'm currently launching the script testssl.sh (http://testssl.sh) on each domain of the list (i.e each line of the file). I'm using GNU parallel to improve performance. Here is how I launch testssl.sh with GNU parallel :

```
cat listDomainNames.txt | parallel --no-notice -j0 --workdir $PWD ./testMX.sh
```

Where testMX.sh launchs testssl.sh :

```
./testssl.sh --starttls smtp --vulnerable --server-preference -mx --append     --csvfile result.csv $1
```

At the begin, my script is testing domain names very quickly (5 000 in 1 single hour) and after several hours, it becomes really slow (like 1 domain per min). Any idea what is happening ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More and more processes will be hanging waiting for timeout.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I saw your post here: https://superuser.com/questions/699432/gnu-parallel-hangs-as-one-process-is-sleeping. So I change my code to that, will it work?    cat listDomainNames.txt | parallel --timeout 200% --no-notice -j0 --workdir $PWD ./testMX.sh

Comment: Yup. That ought to be a good solution if you can live with a few false negatives (And consider running `parallel --bibtex` once).